# Promise does not return the right object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, promise

I have a problem with the following chain of promises:

```
Parse.Cloud.run('cloudlogin', {
        fb_accessToken: $localStorage.accessTokenFacebook
        , facebookID: FACEBOOKID
    }, {
        success: function (userdata) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(userdata))
            $localStorage.username = userdata.username;
            $localStorage.password = userdata.password;
            $localStorage.fb_access_token = userdata.fb_accessToken;
            var bool = userdata.isnewuser
            alert('bool' + bool)
            return bool
        }
        , error: function (error) {
            alert(error)
            $state.go("login")
                .then(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide()
                })
        }
    })
    .then(function (isnewuser) {
        $localStorage.organizerAccess = true;
        alert('fbdata' + JSON.stringify(isnewuser))
    })
```

I would like to make the first promise to return the boolean 'isnewuser' to the second promise but instead the whole 'userdata' object is returned. Any idea?

Comment: can't you just use `userdata.isnewuser`? It seems you already have the property you're looking for in the next promise.

Comment: yes I can obviously, but it's not the right solution.... the problem is why the 'return bool' does not return what is supposed to do

Comment: I believe this has something to do with `Parse.Cloud.run`'s implementation of Promises. A standard HTML Promise would work as you expect, but you're just inputting functions into `Parse.Cloud.run` which probably has its own implementation of a Promise, not a vanilla HTML Promise.

Answer (score 0):

as the documentation says - `then(successCallback, [errorCallback], [notifyCallback])` – regardless of when the promise was or will be resolved or rejected, then calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. The callbacks are called with a single argument: the result or rejection reason. Additionally, the notify callback may be called zero or more times to provide a progress indication, before the promise is resolved or rejected.

so, instead of taking the returned value `then` takes the object returned which caused the `success: function (userdata)` which is `userdata`

Comment: if you want multiple callbacks use `then` instead of `success`

Answer (score 0):

success is a callback function its return value won't pass to the next then. if you want to pass the bool value to next one need to rewrite code like below.

```
Parse.Cloud.run('cloudlogin', {
        fb_accessToken: $localStorage.accessTokenFacebook
        , facebookID: FACEBOOKID
     }, {
         error: function (error) {
            alert(error)
            $state.go("login")
                .then(function () {
                    $ionicLoading.hide()
                })
        }
    }).then(function (userdata) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(userdata))
            $localStorage.username = userdata.username;
            $localStorage.password = userdata.password;
            $localStorage.fb_access_token = userdata.fb_accessToken;
            var bool = userdata.isnewuser
            alert('bool' + bool)
            return bool
        })
    .then(function (isnewuser) {
        $localStorage.organizerAccess = true;
        alert('fbdata' + JSON.stringify(isnewuser))
    })
```

Comment: You probably should also avoid the `error` callback and instead pass it as the `onrejected` parameter to `then`

Answer (score 0):

```
login: function () {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    Parse.Cloud.run('cloudlogin', {
        fb_accessToken: $localStorage.accessTokenFacebook,
        facebookID: FACEBOOKID
    }).error(function (error) {
        alert(error)
        $state.go("login")
        .then(function () {
            $ionicLoading.hide()
        })
    })
    .then(function (userdata) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(userdata))
        $localStorage.username = userdata.username;
        $localStorage.password = userdata.password;
        $localStorage.fb_access_token = userdata.fb_accessToken;
        deferred.resolve(userdata.isnewuser);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

write this function in service class and call it from controller

Comment: This might become a good answer if you explain what you did change in the code and why.

Comment: So,If we can create a service class we can call when ever we want basically  this is angular js workflow.service class is interact with  server code